# JSmooth : how to convert jar with JFrame to exe?

Tags: java, swing, installation, jframe, jsmooth

I had no problem converting console JAR executable to exe
However I am confused how I can convert JAR with JFrame or other GUI options available? What skeleton I have to use? I mean which wrapper I have to use?

Comment: You can deploy a GUI exe in the same way, make sure you have a `main()` method which launches the GUI

Comment: why do you except any difference?

Comment: *"how I can convert JAR with JFrame or other GUI options available?"*  Don't do any conversion.  The better option for deploying desktop apps. is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It works for Windows, OS X & *nix, and provides auto-update & desktop integration, amongst other great features.

Comment: My question was what wrapper I will use in JSmooth to convert JAR with GUI to .exe? Because I have tried every wrapper and still don't find any clue

Comment: 1) Add @NikolayKuznetsov (or whoever) to notify someone of a new comment. 2) Is the `JFrame` in an executable Jar?

Answer (score 0):

We have to use WINDOWED WRAPPER as skeleton in JSmooth, that will handle JFrame, now the problem may be if you don't have [this](http://www.dmt.com/jvm_download.htm) then Jsmooth will not probably function. Though I had JVM, JSmooth has not being able to detect it :(
But when I installed Microsoft VM, its suddenly worked for all GUI, FILE and etc functions!